# Obtain client MAC address in ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, mac-address

How can I obtain the client MAC address with C# code of someone who visits my website?

Comment: I removed the second question. If you want to ask a second question. Feel free to do so.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? uniquely identify your visitors ? what are the acceptable accuracy ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have access to the MAC, you don't need it. The MAC is only known to the router who the computer is connected to.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the MAC address of the sender, because you can't get mac address behind the first router on the path to the client.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, you have to run some code on the client machine. MAC address isn't provoided in the internet. Store some cookie with a guid on the machine, that is not as disliked as running code on the client machine. ;-)

The best thing in my oppinion is to establish a user management on your website and give the peaople a chance to register / login. Then you can track everything around the user.

Comment: This still won't help you if the client has more than one MAC address, or connects over a VPN, etc.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: you're right. The all time best way is to provide a login and a user management on the website.