# Obtaining MAC address

Tags: asp-classic, wifi, mac-address

According to [Obtain client MAC address in ASP.NET Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125045/obtain-client-mac-address-in-asp-net-application), it is not possible. I am not entirely convinced because whenever I connect to Tim Hortons WiFi, my MAC address is known.

Occasionally, the network is slow and I see this URL like this before being redirected to the Connect page:

```
http://timhortonswifi.com/cp/tdl3/index.asp
    ?cmd=login
    &switchip=172.30.129.73
    &mac=60:6c:66:17:1a:83
    &ip=10.40.66.229
    &essid=Tim%20Hortons%20WiFi
    &apname=TDL-ON-NEP-02177-WAP1
    &apgroup=02177
    &url=http%3A%2F%2Fweather%2Egc%2Eca%2Fcity%2Fpages%2Fon-72_metric_e%2Ehtml
```

So according to this URL, the site knows the IP address of the router, my MAC address, the IP address assigned to my device by the router, the network SSID, some other pieces of information, and the URL I was trying to access prior to connecting.

There's two options: Tim Hortons WiFi Basic and Tim Hortons WiFi Plus, where the "Plus" option allows me to connect to any Tim Hortons WiFi access point in Canada automatically with this device. Registration requires an email address, so I'm assuming this is possible by checking the MAC address and storing it in a database that routers ping upon connection. [More info here.](http://www.timhortons.com/ca/en/tools/wifi.html)

According to the extension of this page, I can safely assume it is ASP. How are they obtaining this information?

Comment: I would guess they're using an Active X control or java applet

Comment: @AardVark71 I don't think so because as far as I know, iOS does not support either of those but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your client traffic reaches the first router, that router will route the traffic to the adecuated port, changing the response MAC address with its own MAC address so the answer will be routed to it. And this will happen for each of the routers the packets travel by. So, at the end, the web server will only see the MAC address of the last router where the answer will be sent to be routed back to the previous roter, and this process repeated until the answer reaches the client.

No, there is not way to obtain the MAC address of client *from server side*.

But, what you are seeing is a client sending its information to a server. So, the answer can be converted into "how can i obtain my local mac address and send it to the server?".

Browsers do not allow to read this information. Some properly signed/configured ActiveX or Java applets can do it, but they can be blocked, or you can have some device that will not execute java nor activex, so it is not a reliable way of doing it.

In the case in your post, the easiest way of doing it is configuring the wifi access point dhcp or dns server to serve a proxy configuration file that will allow to configure a redirection to the desired web server, redirection that has been created inside the access point, which have all the shown information in your post.

Comment: So if I'm seeing a *"client sending its information to a server"* but *"browsers do not allow to read this information"*, how does my computer know to send the information? There's no prompts for a Java applet or ActiveX control to be executed, nor are these supported on other platforms such as iOS.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6, when you try to navigate, your browser uses the proxy configuration sent by the access point. This proxy (running inside the same access point) sends to your browser a redirection with all the fields populated. All the information is retrieved  inside the access point, sent to the browser and from here to the web server.